# Java Switch Can not find Symbol Error

Tags: java, switch-statement, symbols

I have a problem in java. It can not find the symbol in my switch function.
I think there is something wrong with char inputChar(i) but I can not figure out the problem.

Here is the code:

```
import eip.*;

public class IntDigitAutomat
{
public static boolean digitCheck(char inputChar)
{
    boolean isdigit = true;
    int q = 1;

    for (int i=0; i<input.length(); i++)
    {
        if(isdigit == false)
            break;
            switch(q)
            {
                case 1:
                    switch(inputChar(i))
                    {
                        case '+':
                        case '-':
                            isdigit = true;
                            q=2;
                            break;

                        case ' ':
                            isdigit = true;
                            q=1;
                            break;

                        case '0':
                        case '1':
                        case '2':
                        case '3':
                        case '4':
                        case '5':
                        case '6':
                        case '7':
                        case '8':
                        case '9':
                            isdigit = true;
                            q=3;
                            break;

                        default:
                            isdigit = false;
                    }


                case 2:
                    switch(inputChar(i))
                    {
                        case '0':
                        case '1':
                        case '2':
                        case '3':
                        case '4':
                        case '5':
                        case '6':
                        case '7':
                        case '8':
                        case '9':
                            isdigit = true;
                            q=3;
                            break;

                        default:
                            isdigit = false;
                    }

                case 3:
                    switch(inputChar(i))
                    {
                        case '0':
                        case '1':
                        case '2':
                        case '3':
                        case '4':
                        case '5':
                        case '6':
                        case '7':
                        case '8':
                        case '9':
                            isdigit = true;
                            break;

                        default:
                            isdigit = false;
                    }
        }
        return isdigit;
    }
}
}
```

I needed more text. I needed more text. I needed more text. I needed more text.

Comment: What symbol can it not find?  What's the actual error message?

Comment: What is `inputChar(i)` supposed to mean?  `inputChar` is a single character.

Comment: `IntDigitAutomat.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
  for (int i=0; i<input.length(); i++)
                  ^
  symbol:   variable input
  location: class IntDigitAutomat
IntDigitAutomat.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
      switch(inputChar(i))
             ^
  symbol:   method inputChar(int)
  location: class IntDigitAutomat
IntDigitAutomat.java:50: error: cannot find symbol`

Comment: since it is in the for-loop, it should proof every position of a row.

Comment: In the for-loop, you haven't defined `input` at all.  That's why there's an error.

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass single character to your switch statement, change `switch(inputChar(i))` to `switch(inputChar)`

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int i=0; i<input.length(); i++)
```

This is where you are getting a problem where is the string or literal that you are supposed to be searching?  where is the String input?

If you are trying to create some kind of math expression parser you are going about it the wrong way.
You should look on google or even other questions here about math parsing.

Also look at the other answer about your inputChar(i) which is also going to solve another error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

your code is not proper if you are using inputchar array then in method attribute take it as array if its not array then loop condition is wrong as well as switch condition is wrong.